# Matlab: Converting a 1x1 sym to double

Tags: matlab

I'm new in MATLAB and I want to convert test(1x1 sym value) in a double value.

How can I do that? This is my current code:

```
function [ xn ] = newton_method( f, x0, h, steps ) 
%f is a symfun 
%x0 is the starting value 
%h is derivation-stepwidth
%steps.. how many calculations 
xn = x0; i = 0; 

while i < steps 
v = f(xn+h)-f(xn); 
derivation = v/h; 
xn = xn - f(xn)/derivation; 
i=i+1; 
output = double(xn) % it returns 1x1 sym and no double
end
```

Comment: have you tried `double(test)`?

Comment: yeah, but when i convert test in my newton_method.m and return test it's 1x1 sym value again..

Comment: function [ xn ] = newton_method( f, x0, h, steps )
%f is a symfun
%x0 is the starting value
%h is derivation-stepwidth
%steps.. how many calculations
xn = x0;
i = 0;
while i < steps
    v =  f(xn+h)-f(xn);
    derivation = v/h;
    xn = xn - f(xn)/derivation;
    i=i+1;
output = double(xn) % it returns 1x1 sym and no double.. why?
end

Comment: Don't put code in comments, press "edit" and format it properly (I've done it for you this time).  Your problem this time is that you don't return `output` at all! Your function only returns `xn`, which is still a sym.

Comment: yeah i have to convert also the step-calculations. then it will return a double. Thank you for the hint! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the [subs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html?refresh=true) function. You replace a symbolic variable with an actual value

```
syms sym_a %a is now a symbolic variable
val_a = subs(sym_a,5.3) % we've replaced the symbolic a with number 5.3
```